# Determine possible values for an attribute

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling with getting the possible values for an attribute.

I want to generate a report of DTCs (Distributed Transaction Coordinators). With the help I found the cmdlet `Get-DtcAdvancedSetting`.

With this `Get-DtcAdvancedSetting` cmdlet it's possible to read the properties. The command looks like this:

```
$AccountName = Get-DtcAdvancedSetting -Name "AccountName" -DtcName "Local" -Subkey "Security"
```

This works perfectly. But to read the other properties I have to find out what Names they have.

How can I find out the possible Values for the -Name attribute of the cmdlet `Get-DtcAdvancedSetting` with the help of PowerShell?

I tried like this:

```
Get-DtcAdvancedSetting -Name "AccountName" -DtcName "Local" -Subkey "Security"  |
    Select Name -First 1 |
    Get-Member
[Enum]::GetNames('System.String.Name')
```

I also tried like this:

```
Get-Command Get-DtcAdvancedSetting |
    %{$_.Parameters.Values} |
    fl name, ParameterType
[Enum]::GetNames('Microsoft.System.String')
```

Both ways just give me failures like:

> Cannot convert argument "enumType", with value:

Is it possible the get this Values? And if yes how?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the parameters of the `Get-DtcAdvancedSetting` cmdlet? Or the properties of the object `$dtc`? And to what end? What do you want to do with that information?

Comment: Hello Ansgar. I want to get the possible Values for the Parameter -Name of the cmdlet Get-DtcAdvancedSetting. Otherwise i cannot read the rest of the properties... What i want to do with this information? Generate a report. But all this information is already included in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Get-DtcAdvancedSetting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msdtc/get-dtcadvancedsetting?view=win10-ps) cmdlet allows you to query the registry.

So in your case you are probably searching for

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC | Select -ExpandProperty Property
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. You read my question right :) Just one thing, next time i would like to get to this solution by myself. Can you explain to me where you got the registry path from? And why "select -ExpandProperty Property"?

Comment: For example, what would i have to change to check the possible Values of the Attribute -Subkey from the same cmdlet get-dtcadvancedsetting?

Comment: You can get the documentation for cmdlets via ```get-help Get-DtcAdvancedSetting -Online``` - there you can read that the cmdlet provides easier access to the DTC registry keys. The rest is reading the registry with powershell. You need the ExpandProperty Property because there are several subkeys with the property "Property"

Comment: Ah ok thats clear now. Thanks a lot & have a nice day!